# AngularJS apply filter in javascript instead of html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat to create table:

```
ng-repeat="equipment in equipments | filter: equipmentFilter | dateFilter: dateStart: dateEnd | pageFilter: currentPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize"
```

I need to get:

```
(equipments | dateFilter: dateStart: dateEnd | filter: equipmentFilter).length
```

to update number of total page in paging feature. I've tried:

```
ng-init="equipmentsForPaging = (equipments | dateFilter: dateStart: dateEnd | filter: equipmentFilter)"
```

But it isn't working at all, also I don't think using ng-init is a good idea. So are there anyway to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), you can inject and use it in your controller.

But if you use that, you will re use filter so there are 2 filter treatments (2 loops) so in my opinion it's not good idea.

You already got that filtered array in your view, you just need to assign it to a variable, in the ng-repeat, and use parenthesis to distinct your needed array:

`ng-repeat="equipment in filtered = (equipments | filter: equipmentFilter | dateFilter: dateStart: dateEnd) | pageFilter: currentPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize`"

then you can just use `{{filtered.length}}`

Comment: Wow, I have no idea it's that easy. But how can I inject the 'dateFilter' in javascript since it got 2 argument? And does $filter modified the array input?

Comment: It'a a filter, created by app.filter(), eg: .filter('dateFilter', function() { return function( items, fromDate, toDate ) {...}); 
 you can use $filter('dateFilter')(array, fromDate, toDate)